# Using classes in PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to coding my PHP scripts with classes but it is very difficult to learn. The transition from the old style making me trouble. I know why to use classes but my question is. Can I code everything using classes? Is it effective? Or sometimes "the old style" is better.

Ok. I try to be more specific. Can be this code write with classes?

```
<?php
$error = array("Odpad nebol zapísaný!");
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
$note = isset($_POST['note']) ? $_POST['note'] : '';
$rozmer=$oznacenie_pracoviska=$oznacenie_odpadu=$meno=$vaha=$zberne_miesto="";

if (is_numeric($_POST["zakazka1"]) && is_numeric($_POST["zakazka2"]) && is_numeric($_POST["zakazka3"])) {

    function countDigits($str) {
    return preg_match_all( "/[0-9]/", $str );
    }

    if (countDigits($_POST["zakazka1"])==3 && countDigits($_POST["zakazka3"])==2) {
        $zakazka = array($_POST["zakazka1"],$_POST["zakazka2"],$_POST["zakazka3"]);
        $zakazka_cela = implode("/", $zakazka);
    }

    else {  
        $error[]="Zadajte správny počet číslic v zákazke!";
    }

}

else {
   $error[]="Zadajte číslo zákazky!";
}


if (empty($_POST["rozmer"])) {
    $error[]="Zadajte rozmer!";
}

else {
    $rozmer=$_POST["rozmer"];
}

if (empty($_POST["oznacenie_odpadu"])) {
    $error[]="Zadajte označenie odpadu!";
}

else {
    $oznacenie_odpadu=$_POST["oznacenie_odpadu"];
}

 if (empty($_POST["vaha"])) {
    $error[]="Zadajte váhu!";
}

else {
    $output = str_replace(',', '.', $_POST["vaha"]);

    if (is_numeric($output)) {
        $vaha = str_replace('.', ',', $_POST["vaha"]);
    }

    else {
       $error[]="Váha zadaná v zlom formáte!";
    }
}

if (empty($_POST["oznacenie_pracoviska"])) {
    $error[]="Zadajte označenie pracoviska!";
}

else {
    $oznacenie_pracoviska=$_POST["oznacenie_pracoviska"];
}

 if (empty($_POST["meno"])) {
    $error[]="Zadajte meno!";
}

else {
    $meno=$_POST["meno"];
}

if (empty($_POST["zberne_miesto"])) {
    $error[]="Zadajte kód zberného miesta!";
}

else {
    $zberne_miesto=$_POST["zberne_miesto"];
}

}
```

Comment: not sure what you mean by `Old Style` but php thrives on OOP for security and DRY-ness (don't repeat yourself) knowing how classes work will make PHP a million times more fun to use. Do you have a specific question on classes? or the ideologies behind them? if not I have to flag this as "Too Broad" :/

Comment: I believe the `Zend` framework prides itself on being 100% OOP instead of procedural....aka *"Old style"*, so yes, it is possible to code everything with classes.

Comment: You could code this snippit in a class, but it wouldn't be a very good class. In terms of doing something, it's not really doing anything except some basic validation and error handling. I think it would need to be part of a bigger task so whatever you are using this for might be more useful for the rest of the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all OOP is not difficult to learn. If your brain starts thinking that it is difficult so you will never be able to learn it properly and you will never enjoy the OOP style. OOP php has a lot of effective features which makes programming easier and more readable. Start learning OOP in php and i am sure you will enjoy it. You can do everything in OOP what you can do in procedural. although you can use classes in procedural style and that is also an awesome way of PHP programming.